# Можно ли так использовать тире для перехода к основной части после перечисления, а потом снова переходить к уже другому перечислению?

Tags: пунктуация

Капитал может быть физическим, например: станки, здания, промышленное оборудование, закупленное сырье, техника и другое – и может быть финансовым: ценные бумаги, драгоценные металлы, валюта, деньги, инвестиции.

Answer (score 1):

Постановка знаков препинания в таком предложении делается с учетом правила Розенталя, п. 8: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103

Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения **требуется постановка запятой,** то она ставится, а тире или ставится, или опускается. Ср.: Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, — есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие (Сол.) — запятая закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием наряду с; **Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки** (Г.) — **запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.**

В данном случае между однородными сказуемыми знака нет, но ввиду их распространенности пауза явно присутствует, поэтому предложение можно приравнять к сложному предложению. В этом случае можно поставить **запятую или запятую и тире,** если при сопоставлении пауза подчеркивается.

(1) *Капитал может быть физическим, например: станки, здания, промышленное оборудование, закупленное сырье, техника,  **и может быть** финансовым: ценные бумаги, драгоценные металлы, валюта, деньги, инвестиции.*

(2) *Капитал может быть физическим, например: станки, здания, промышленное оборудование, закупленное сырье, техника, — **и может быть** финансовым: ценные бумаги, драгоценные металлы, валюта, деньги, инвестиции*.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен сам вопрос, непонятно, каким образом перечисление, даже два, могут предопределять или запрещать постановку подобного тире. И обратно.
Тире ставится для передачи периода во фразе, распадающейся на две противопоставляемых части. Здесь вопрос применения такого правила несколько спорен, поскольку противопоставляются не части фразы, а лишь части её фрагмента, но в любом случае есть понятие "интонационного тире", которое как "авторский знак" может применяться более широко.

Если же безотносительно к перечислениям, то я не вижу, к чему по части пунктуации тут можно было бы придраться. Наоборот, использование даже интонационного (необязательного) тире решает все проблемы с пониманием.

Есть маленькое замечание по стилистике. Если использовано "например", то и "другое" обычно избыточно: и так понятно, что список неполный. Но это уже совсем другой уровень.